# Delay in Flipping Sprites , Coroutines not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
GameObject playerObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
playerTransform = playerObject.transform;
Vector3 direction = playerTransform.position - transform.position;
direction.y = 0f; // Ignore the Y component, only move along the X-axis
direction.Normalize(); // Normalize to get a unit vector

float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, playerTransform.transform.position);
// Debug.Log(distanceToPlayer);

transform.Translate(new Vector3(direction.x, 0f, 0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime); // moves the boss

Debug.Log(direction.x);
if (direction.x > 0f)
{
    // Face right
    StartCoroutine(TurnBossR());
}
else if (direction.x < 0f)
{
    // Face left
    StartCoroutine(TurnBossL());
}

IEnumerator TurnBossR()
{
    // Face right
    sr.flipX = false;
    Debug.Log("Right");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}

IEnumerator TurnBossL()
{
    // Face Left
    sr.flipX = true;
    Debug.Log("Left");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve is the Boss would change directions(left or right facing) with a delay of a few seconds.

The issue is that the boss isn't flipping sprites at all, I have the `GetComponent` of `SpriteRenderer` all dealt with, in the console its updating the value of `direction.x` and the `Debug.Log` inside the `IEnumerators`.

```
public class BossManager : Enemy, IDamageable
{
    int IDamageable.health { get; set; }

    private Transform playerTransform;

    private bool seq;
    private Animator animator;

    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    //public Vector3 position;
    //public Quaternion rotation;
    void Start()
    {
        sr = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();  
    }
}
```

As you can see the issue isn't with getting the component for the `SpriteRenderer`.

Comment: you are potentially starting a coroutine every frame when x is not 0 ..

Comment: ok then what should i do ?

Comment: debug it. Find out what it thinks its doing

Comment: you should ensure only one routine is running at a time .. or if this is called every frame maybe not use a Coroutine at all but rather a simple timer (`timer -= Time.deltaTime`) ... Depends a bit on what exactly you are trying to achieve ... e.g. should the boss always turn to your position 1s after you have moved there? E.g. if you go left but within 1s go right it wouldn't turn at all? Or do you rather simply want to sample/check/assess the position in intervals of 1s and turn to wherever you are in that moment? Etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your update function, you are constantly running Coroutines again and again. Coroutines are like individual methods, so it does not matter if you put a wait inside the coroutine because it another one of them will get run in the next frame. Here is an example of another way to accomplish what you are doing using timers:

https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/70d4254e